# In python3 I am checking a URL. when it fails DNS lookup or doesn't exist I don't want a traceback. I want invalid URL

Tags: python-3.x, xml, url, python-requests, traceback

The input URL is: http://fnserver <<<--- doesn't exist doesn't resolve.

```
 try:
        response = requests.request("GET", url=url, verify=False, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, passwd))
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print ("Http Error:",errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print ("OOps: Something Else",err)
```

the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was looking for.

```
import traceback as tb
    url = input("Please enter the URL: ")
    print("Testing URL '{}'".format(url))
    try:
         r = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
         url = input("Connection error Enter new URL: \n")
         tb.print_tb(tb,limit=0,file=None)
```

Here is where I found it https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html